# Value not passing properly in javascript function while iterator using $.each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, ajax

I am returning array of object called "categories" from the Ajax call and then i am replacing its object(category) value in the string(categoriesList). Then i am replacing this string in the html div Area as  `$("#divAreaName").html("StringName");`

For proper understanding the code is shown below:

```
$.each(categories,function(index,category){
    categoriesList = categoriesList + 
    "<div class='media'>"+
        "<img onclick=dispProductCategoryWise('"+category.name+"','"+category.id+"','"+id+"','"+retailerId+"'); src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}"+category.image+"'>"+
    "</div>"+
    "<div class='item-info'>"+
        "<div class='item-name item-row'>"+
            "<span class='full-item-name'>"+category.name+"</span>"+
        "</div>"+
    "</div>";
});
```

Then i am replacing the string in the div area using the following line of code

```
$("#divName").html(categoriesList);
```

However the problem is when category.name is "Fruits and Vegetable". The HTML is formed as shown below:

```
<img onclick="dispProductCategoryWise('Fruits" &="" Vegetable','60','1','2');="" src="/closerby/images/customer/category/FandV.jpeg">
```

Can someone let me know why the values are not getting passed properly and the possible solution?

Comment: Add the `categories` array in question

Comment: What will be the possible solution of it?

Comment: I think your `"<img onclick=dispProductCategoryWise(` is missing an opening quote for the value of the onclick attribute, also, whats the semicolon after the onclick attribute

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem, it seems the spaces are strangely converted when using `.html()`. As if the `'`/`"` itself are rendered. `console.log` gives correct string as well.

As an alternative, create an event on that specific image using a dynamically generated id.

Like so:

```
categories = {
        "category":{
            "name": "Fruits and Vegetables",
            "id": 1,
        }
    }

    $.each(categories,function(index,category){
        categoriesList = 
        "<div class='media'>"+
            "<img id='specific_"+index+"' src='{somethingwashere}'>"+
        "</div>"+
        "<div class='item-info'>"+
            "<div class='item-name item-row'>"+
                "<span class='full-item-name'>"+category.name+"</span>"+
            "</div>"+
        "</div>";
        $("#myDiv").html(categoriesList);
        //Added event.
        $('#specific_'+index).click(function() {
            return displayProductCategoryWise(category.name, category.id);  
        });
    }); 

    function displayProductCategoryWise(name, id) {
        alert(name);
        alert(id);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ive only used `$('selector').each(fn)` to do something for each matched jquery element

Perhaps try using `categories.forEach(function(category, index){ ...`

Comment: I had used $.each(categories,function(index,category){ }); and it is iterating to each object of the arraylist. The problem lies at the time of substituting the value of the object.

Comment: Even  though i will try your approach too and get back to you

Answer (score -1):

Are you turning the quote makes into special characters..... add a blackslash ()

Something like :

```
<img onclick=dispProductCategoryWise('\"+category.name+\"','\"+category.id+\"','\"+id+\"','\"+retailerId+\"'); src='${pageContext.request.contextPath}\"+category.image+\"'>\"
```

Comment: Actually it's even worse